# Feature tests in nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, nestjs

I am new to testing and my boss said I have to implement feature test for command service to creatie a workspace entity. This feature test is different from unit test (which I have never written before either :v) and don't require mocking. Here is something I have done for the test:

```
// workspaces.commands.service.spec.ts
// imported necessary libs

describe('Test workspace command service', () => {
  let commandService: WorkspacesCommandService;
  let repository: WorkspacesRepository;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const typeOrmModule = getTestingModuleTypeOrmRoot([Workspace]);
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [...typeOrmModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([WorkspacesRepository])],
      providers: [WorkspacesCommandService],
    }).compile();

    commandService = await module.get(WorkspacesCommandService);
    repository = await module.get(WorkspacesRepository);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(commandService).toBeDefined();
    expect(repository).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should create a workspace', async () => {
    const createWorkspaceDto: CreateWorkspaceDto = {
      name: 'jane',
      status: 1,
    };

    const createdWorkspace = await commandService.create(createWorkspaceDto);

    expect(createdWorkspace).toBeInstanceOf(Workspace);
    expect(createdWorkspace.id).not.toBeNull();
    expect(createdWorkspace.domain).toBeNull();
    expect(createdWorkspace.name).toEqual(createWorkspaceDto.name);
    expect(createdWorkspace.status).toEqual(createWorkspaceDto.status);
  });
});
```

and here are some related files. I will start with the workspaces.commands.ts

```
//imported libs

@Injectable()
export class WorkspacesCommandService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(WorkspacesRepository)
    private readonly workspacesRepository: WorkspacesRepository
  ) {}

  async create({ ...createWorkspaceDto }: CreateWorkspaceDto) {
    try {
      const workspace = await this.workspacesRepository.save(createWorkspaceDto);
      return plainToClass(Workspace, workspace);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw new Error('Failed to create workspace');
    }
  }

  async update({ ...updateWorkspaceDto }: UpdateWorkspaceDto) {
    try {
      const workspace = await this.workspacesRepository.findOne(updateWorkspaceDto.id);
      if (!workspace) {
        throw new Error('Workspace not found');
      }

      const updatedWorkspace = await this.workspacesRepository.save(workspace);
      return updatedWorkspace;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Failed to update workspace');
    }
  }

  async delete({ ...deleteWorkspaceDto }: DeleteWorkspaceDto) {
    try {
      const workspace = await this.workspacesRepository.findOne(deleteWorkspaceDto.id);
      if (!workspace) {
        throw new Error('Workspace not found');
      }
      await this.workspacesRepository.remove(workspace);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Failed to delete workspace');
    }
  }
}
```

here is the create-workspace.dto:

```
//imported libs

export class CreateWorkspaceDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Transform(({ value }) => value?.trim())
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Transform(({ value }) => value?.trim())
  @ApiProperty()
  @Optional()
  domain?: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Transform(({ value }) => value?.trim())
  @ApiProperty()
  status: number;
}
```

and here is the entity workspace file with typeorm form:

```
@Entity('workspace')
export class Workspace {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  domain: string;

  @Column()
  status: number;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at' })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

My question is: did I implement the feature test correctly? What is the flow of the code/data when I run the test (going from dto -> service -> repo -> sqlite3, sorry I did not mentioned sqlite3 for testing)? Is there any example of the feature test and unit test regarding to my case?

Hope that you guys can help